# MySQL Query Failed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

With the following code (html / SQL) the code fails to execute. I'm entirely great at MySQL but here is my code:

### Requested Orders

Input Item and Quantity

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_one" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_two" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_three" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_four" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_five" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_six" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_seven" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_eight" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_nine" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_ten" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_eleven" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_twelve" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_thirteen" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_fourteen" size="40"><br>

<input type="text" name="item_fifthteen" size="40"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sent">
```

Here is the function.php

```
<?php
//the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form
//function.php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
mysql_select_db("order_db");

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO requested_inventory
            (name, email, item_one, item_two, item_three, item_four, item_five, item_six, item_seven, item_eight, item_nine, item_ten, item_eleven, item_twelve, item_thirteen, item_fourteen, item_fifthteen)
            VALUES
            ('name',
            'email', 'item_one', 'item_two', 'item_three', 'item_four', 'item_five', 'item_six', 'item_seven', 'item_eight', 'item_eight', 'item_nine', 'item_ten', 'item_eleven', 'item_twelve', 'item_thirteen', 'item_fourteen', 'item_fifthteen')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query('$order');    //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
?>
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong. Any help with examples would be much appreciated.

note: This is on a localhost machine so there is no need to full on security which is why I'm using root without a password.

Comment: Why don't you paste the error message?

Comment: @Lion There is no error message being generated, nothing is being stored in the table.

Comment: Errors should be there, if you enabled.

Comment: BTW you might want to change from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` or something else like `pdo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra field `item_eight` 2 times.try like

```
"INSERT INTO requested_inventory
(name, email, item_one, item_two, item_three, item_four, item_five, item_six, item_seven, item_eight, item_nine, item_ten, item_eleven, item_twelve, item_thirteen, item_fourteen, item_fifthteen)
VALUES
('name','email', 'item_one', 'item_two', 'item_three', 'item_four', 'item_five', 'item_six', 'item_seven', 'item_eight', 'item_nine', 'item_ten', 'item_eleven', 'item_twelve', 'item_thirteen', 'item_fourteen', 'item_fifthteen')";
```

And also try to execute like

```
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

As per your comment try to execute the insert query like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requested_inventory`
(name varchar(20), email varchar(20), item_one varchar(20), item_two varchar(20), item_three varchar(20), item_four varchar(20), item_five varchar(20), item_six varchar(20), item_seven varchar(20), item_eight varchar(20), item_nine varchar(20), item_ten varchar(20), item_eleven varchar(20), item_twelve varchar(20), item_thirteen varchar(20), item_fourteen varchar(20), item_fifthteen varchar(20));
```

You can change the datatypes as per your requeriment

Comment: Yep, I was just about to answer the same thing

Comment: @Gautam3164 Fixed both and the issue still stands.

Comment: @Gautam3164 I'm being told that the table order_db.requested_inventory doesn't exist. What SQL code do I execute in PHPMyAdmin to create the relevant columns and table?

Comment: @Gautam3164 Now its working however the input from the HTML form isn't entering in, the fields in the db are set the name of the field.

Comment: yes You need to insert the posted variables like $_POST['name']....like that.I thought you are inserting demo data.You can accept it if you can

Comment: @Gautam3164 Answer has been accepted.

When I change the values to for example '$name' I am getting an error message
    Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\function.php on line 9

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
$result = mysql_query('$order');
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

Inside single quotes variable is treated as normal text. Use either direct variable name OR enclose it within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($order);
```

replace this 
  and  kindly check the id  field  is that auto incremented or not  also kindly provide the error message  you are  getting

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$order = "INSERT INTO requested_inventory
            (name, email, item_one, item_two, item_three, item_four, item_five, item_six, item_seven, item_eight, item_nine, item_ten, item_eleven, item_twelve, item_thirteen, item_fourteen, item_fifthteen)
            VALUES
            ('$_REQUEST[name]',
            '$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[item_one]', '$_REQUEST[item_two]', '$_REQUEST[item_three]', '$_REQUEST[item_four]', '$_REQUEST[item_five]', '$_REQUEST[item_six]', '$_REQUEST[item_seven]', '$_REQUEST[item_eight]', '$_REQUEST[item_eight]', '$_REQUEST[item_nine]', '$_REQUEST[item_ten]', '$_REQUEST[item_eleven]', '$_REQUEST[item_twelve]', '$_REQUEST[item_thirteen]', '$_REQUEST[item_fourteen]', '$_REQUEST[item_fifthteen]')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);    //order executes

?>
```

Also add `mysql_real_escape_string` to your query

Also to inform you `mysql_query` is no longer supported